# A function that grows faster than any function in the sequence $e^x, e^{e^x}, e^{e^{e^x}}$...

Tags: calculus, functions, exponential-function, elementary-functions

Is there a continuous function constructed by elementary functions, or by integral formula involved only elementary functions (like Gamma function) that grows faster than any $e^{e^{e...^x}}$ ($e$ appears $n$ times)?

I ask for the answer with a single formula. Gluing continuous function together is too trivial.

The function need not to be defined on whole $\mathbb{R}$, the domain $(a, \infty)$ is acceptable.

Comment: Do you accept iterative procedures? If so [The Ackermann Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) generalises the series addition, multiplication, exponentiation. Likewise [Knuth's Arrow Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation).

Comment: @AlphaNumeric Nope :)

Comment: Have you ever seen Graham's number. That may be what you're looking for. [Check it on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number)

Comment: I suppose that applying any of the allowed operations (composition with elementasry function or integration) turns a function that is bounded by some e-tower into a function bounded by some (possibly higher) e-tower.

Comment: Perhaps an annoying example, but for any $\;a>e\;,\;\;a^{a^{a\ldots^x}}\;$ grows faster

Comment: @CarlosAfonso Thank you but I asked for continuous functions.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yeah, only if the towers have the same height.

Comment: @DonAntonio By asking this question, I mean a function that grows faster than every "tower of $e$"

Comment: I suppose you mean to find a function $f$ that eventually grows faster than each function in the set $\{exp^n(x)\mid n\in\Bbb N\}$, where $n$ in the power denotes iteration of function.

Comment: @edm Yeah, that's was I mean

Comment: An elementary function is a finite expression of functions of some type. So you could simply do a induction on the length of this expression to show that this does not fast enough? On the other hand if you allow iterative things you are able two write down a function $f$ with $f(n) > exp^n(n)$ as an infinite sum.

Comment: @user60589 That's a promising route to a nonexistence proof. Can you turn it into an answer?

Comment: What do you mean by "gluing continuous function"?

Comment: I mean define $f(x) =$ $C_k$ + exp(exp(..(x)) (k iterations) on $[k, k+1]$, $C_k$ is chosen so that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @edm I don't know an appropriate term for this trick. Could you suggest me one?

Comment: @Pluviophile I don't know a name for this, but I almost gave an answer in this form. I have thought of $\exp^{\lfloor x\rfloor}(x)$ and $\exp^{\lfloor\exp x\rfloor}(x)$, which are both piecewise continuous. The number of iterations is a function of $x$, which I think is good enough. A simple translation would make them continuous. Notice that the function generated from "sticking" the graph of $\exp^{\lfloor x\rfloor}(x)$ is equivalent to the function you mentioned.

Comment: replace e with any real number larger than e

Comment: Related: [Smooth Elementary Function that Outgrows All Tower Functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3061441)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**a negative answer**
No, there is no such function constructed in a "natural" way, if we construe that word propertly.

Perhaps consult the literature on "transseries" ...

For example, transseries in the sense here:
G. A. Edgar, "Transseries for Beginners". *Real Analysis Exchange* **35** (2010) 253-310 .

The set of transseries includes real elementary functions, is closed under indefinite integration, composition, and many other operations.

But no transseries has growth rate beyond all $e^{\dots e^x}$. There is an integer "exponentiality" associated with each (large, positive) transseries; for example Exercise 4.10 in:
J. van der Hoeven, *Transseries and Real Differential Algebra* (LNM 1888) (Springer 2006)

A (large, positive) transseries with exponentiality $n+1$ grows faster than any transseries with exponentiality ${} \le n$.
And $e^{\dots e^x}$ with $n$ exponentiations has exponentiality $n$.

Comment: If $f$ is a power series that converges on $\mathbb{R}$, do we still get a negative answer?

Answer (score 6):

Here is a proof that there is no such function und elementary function.

Let $A$ be a collection of functions which grow slower than the collection $e^x, e^{e^x} , \dots $.

We know that the sum, product composition and integral of functions which grow slower than $e^x, e^{e^x} , \dots $ also grows slower that $e^x, e^{e^x} , \dots $.

Then the set of functions which are finite iterate sums, $\dots$ of functions in $A$ also grows slower that $e^x, e^{e^x} , \dots $

Now, depending on or definition of elementary function, if you take $A= \{1, x, \exp, \log, x^a \}$ you should be done.