# Smooth Elementary Function that Outgrows All Tower Functions?

Tags: elementary-functions, tetration, power-towers, smooth-functions

This started off with me goofing off on Twitter and quickly led to this question to which I didn't know the answer.

Let $T_2(x) = x^x$, $T_3(x) = x^{x{^x}}$, $T_4(x) = x^{x^{x^x}}$, and so forth.

Is there a $C^{\infty}$ elementary function $f(x)$ (it can be piecewise-defined) with $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{T_k(x)} = \infty$ for all $k$? If so, what is a (possibly piecewise-defined) formula for such an $f$?

Comment: (I tried $f(x) = T_k(x)$ on [k+(1/4), k+(3/4)] and linearly interpolating between endpoints, but I couldn't find a way to make that both smooth (convoluting with Gaussians would do that, but it wouldn't be elementary then) and elementary (it's already elementary but not smooth.)

Comment: Possibly related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1892870/a-function-that-grows-faster-than-any-function-in-the-sequence-ex-eex-e

Comment: (The Smooth Approximation Theorem from differential topology also does not guarantee an elementary solution.)

Comment: @Martin R. Mmm, the second answer in that question in close, but doesn't allow piecewise-defined functions; I already found an elementary piecewise-defined function that contradicts the second answer.

Comment: I am no expert on this topic at all. My *guess* would be that a similar approach as in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1892870/a-function-that-grows-faster-than-any-function-in-the-sequence-ex-eex-e#comment3882533_1892870) might work: Define $f$ on the positive integers as $f(k) = T_k(k)$, and smoothly interpolate between the integers.

Comment: @JeffreyRolland [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) are, by definition, not defined piecewise. They are, more or less, compositions of $(+,-,\times,\div)$, exponentials, logarithms, and inverses of polynomials.

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer:

There are no such [elementary functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1892986), the below constructions are non-elementary but still interesting.

---

For starters, one can construct a simple $C^k$ function for any $k\in\mathbb N$ simply by integrating as follows:

$$\int_1^x\int_1^{x_1}\dots\int_1^{x_k}T_{\lfloor x_{k+1}\rfloor}(\lfloor x_{k+1}\rfloor)~\mathrm dx_{k+1}~\mathrm dx_k\dots\mathrm dx_2~\mathrm dx_1$$

which is trivially $k$ times continuously differentiable and grows faster than $T_m(x)$ for all $m\in\mathbb N$.

---

For $C^\infty$ functions, I give special mentions to [Wojowu](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/127263) a.k.a. LittlePeng9 for [fast growing analytic functions](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:LittlePeng9/Fast_growing_hierarchy_of_analytic_functions). I will give a slightly simplified construction here.

> Let $f:\mathbb C\mapsto\mathbb C$ satisfy the following properties:
>
> 1. $f$ is [entire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/entire_function).
> 2. $|f(z)|\le z$ for all $|z|<1$.
>
> Consider the following function:
>
> $$g(z):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f^n\left(\frac z{2^n}\right)$$
>
> where $f^n$ denotes [function iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function#Definition) i.e. $f^2(x)=f(f(x)),f^3(x)=f(f(f(x))),$ etc.

---

For $|z|<1$ we have

$$|f^n(z)|=|f(f^{n-1}(z))|\le|f^{n-1}(z)|\le\dots\le|z|$$

it follows that $|g(z)|\le|z|$ when $|z|<1$ by the geometric series.

Likewise, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}z/2^n=0$ for all $z$, from the [Weierstrass M-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test), it follows that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f^n\left(\frac z{2^n}\right)$ converges uniformly everywhere and hence is [entire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_analyticity).

Now, on the other hand, if $f$ is increasing on $\mathbb R^+$ (and hence positive on $\mathbb R^+$), then for all $N\in\mathbb N$ and $x\in\mathbb R^+$, we have $g(x)\ge f^N(x/2^N)$.

And since $g$ satisfies all the conditions that $f$ required, this can be repeatedly applied to generate increasingly faster growing analytic functions.

---

Take, for example $f(z)=\frac12(e^z-1)$, which satisfies all of the requirements. The corresponding $g$ defined above hence grows faster than $f^N(x/2^N)$ for all $N$, and hence faster than your functions, namely since:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{g(x)}{T_k(x)}\ge\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f^{k+1}(x/2^{k+1})}{T_k(x)}=+\infty$$

For justification of the last limit, one can easily see that $f(x)$ is eventually greater than $2^x$, and that $x<2^x\le x^x\le(2^x)^x=2^{x^2}\le2^{2^x}\le x^{x^x}\le\dots$